# Can not run a script downloaded with 'wget -o filename.sh <URL>'

Tags: command-line, wget

I ran this:

```
wget -o ready-for.sh "https://training.linuxfoundation.org/cm/prep/ready-for.sh"
chmod a+x ./ready-for.sh
./ready-for.sh LFS265
```

and got the error:

```
ready-for.sh line-1 command not found
```

Answer (score 14):

You have used the wrong option of `wget`.

To save a document/file, you need `-O` (capital o). To save the log i.e. whatever shown on STDERR, you need `-o`.

As you were using `-o`, you have saved the logs as `ready-for.sh` and presumably that file does not contain anything understandable by `bash`, hence the error.

In a nutshell, do:

```
wget -O ready-for.sh "https://training.linuxfoundation.org/cm/prep/ready-for.sh"
```

Then you should be able to execute to execute the script, `ready-for.sh`, in the usual manner.

Also don't forget to check `man wget`.

Comment: In this case the `-O ready-for.sh` could be omitted because the file name on the server is already the same, therefore specifying it again is not necessary.